# How to implement share with image for Google+ using angular?

Tags: angularjs, google-plus

i have a problem : I'm trying to share a link in Google plus using the "rules" explained in [Google snippet developers guide](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/), i've tried using itemprops attributes, but it doesn't work, I can't see the image specified in `itemprop="image"`, neither the title and description. So I tried using the metas `og:image` `og:title` etc. and it doesn't work. Both itemprop attributes and og metas are populated with angular variables. There's someone who knows how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you rendering those values server-side for each request? Or only on the client?

Comment: Finally I wrote a server-side page that populates the meta and implemented a rewrite rule to redirect crawlers there.